# Adding custom style to transactional email variables

Tags: html, magento

On my transaction emails for new orders, I want to add custom style (border) or make the output of

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}
```

and

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
```

tabular. I.e **name**, **address** and **tel** fields come out in tabular form with borders.

Comment: You can use inline styles for these.

Comment: can you please guide me on how to add the inline css to {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}} so the output can be bordered?

Comment: <div style="background:#e0eaef;border:1px solid #edfa; padding:0;">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</div>      This is just an example without your code it is difficult to help.